# Bash strips "N" character when using newline-delimiter

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I am using Windows Linux Subsystem (Ubuntu). When I try to set a newline-delimiter, I lose my 'n'-characters. My simplified script;

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $HOME #gives /home/hennio
IFS=$'\n'
echo $HOME #gives /home/he  io
```

`IFS=$'\n\b'` didnt solve the problem. I checked my shebang with $(which sh), it is correct (although using zsh).

Searching on internet didnt give any results. Can someone please tell me whats going on? It driving me nuts..

Comment: A shell invoked as `/bin/sh` usually tries to emulate a POSIX shell. 
 POSIX does not support `$'..'`.  Try using the shebang of a shell that supports `$'...'`.

Comment: Changing it in `#!/bin/bash` did the trick! Thank you very much John!

Comment: Setting the value of `IFS` globally is rarely what you really want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To maintain compatibility, a shell invoked as `/bin/sh` usually tries to emulate a POSIX shell or some variant of a Bourne shell. Neither POSIX nor Bourne support `$'...'`.  There are two possible solutions:

*Method 1:* Use the shebang of a shell, like `bash`, that supports `$'...'`.

Or,

*Method 2:* Use a POSIX method to assigning a newline to `IFS`:

```
IFS='
'
```

(Hat tip: [Gordon Davisson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89817/gordon-davisson))

#### Documentation

From `man zsh`:

> `Zsh` tries to emulate `sh` or `ksh` when it is invoked as `sh` or `ksh`
>   respectively

From `man bash`:

> If  `bash`  is invoked with the name `sh`, it tries to mimic the
>   startup behavior of historical versions of sh as closely as possible,
>   while conforming to the POSIX standard as well.

Comment: If you want to set `IFS` to a newline portably, you can put `IFS='` on one line, and a single `'` on the next line of the script. The shell will interpret the intervening newline as the string to assign `IFS` to.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Excellent suggestion.  Answer updated with your POSIX solution.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers! Im fairly new to bash scripting so you helped me a lot..